# How do you get Math.max to give you the variables name

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

i've written

```
var i = 0;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var z = 0;
```

each variable is incremented by the user, however when i write

```
function blue() {
    console.log(Math.max(i, x, y, z))
}
```

then I simply get back the highest number, not the name of the highest variable. The goal for this code eventually is to tell the user what number they are, and link them to the corresponding number's information. I've tried converting to an array however I'm a beginner with javascript and unsure where to go from here, would greatly appreciate any advice :)

repository for code in question is: https://github.com/LukeMcHenry311/showingproblem
inside of quiz folder
test.html
test.js

Comment: Variables are labels for things you use in code. At runtime if `x` is `4` there is no link from the value to the variable it belongs to.

Comment: A bit of a ugly solution but you could make as many `if` conditions as you have variables and just check if the returned number from `Math.max()` is the same as the one in the `if` condition. Please don't do this if you have a lot of variables but if it's just four or a bit more, like in the example,  it will be fine.

Comment: yeah there are only 4 variables, only problem is is that i can't predict exactly what the number is going to be by the time the user is done with the activity that increments the 4 variables, I wanted to write something like IF i is the greatest of the 4 variables THEN give the user result i and so on with x,y,z giving their result if they are highest

Comment: Okay, so forget my first comment. I just looked in your repository and I think I know what you want to do, so I think [Objects](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) might be what you want/need. Shouldn't be to complicated. Just make four objects  with an id instead of the variables you use now and just add as many properties as you need, like the name of the house.

Comment: And in addition to my second comment use one of the answer that were submitted, that should do it.

Comment: hey thanks for the help bluejambo, sorry was distracted looking at some of the answers. greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var i = 1;
var x = 3;
var y = 2;
var z = 0;

console.log(Object.entries({i,x,y,z}).sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
var i = 1;
var x = 3;
var y = 2;
var z = 0;
max = Object.entries({ i, x, y, z }).reduce(function(carry, [key, value]) {
  if (value > carry.value) {
    carry.key = key
    carry.value = value
  }
  return carry
}, { 'key': null, 'value': null });
console.log(max); // { key: 'x', value: 3 }
```